# How does one emphasize something in Spanish?

Tags: gramática

Consider the following sentence:

> I'm in *your* country, therefore I'll speak Spanish.

Notice the emphasis is on 'your'. How would this translate to Spanish?

Comment: Esto en el pais tuyo.  It's a nontraditional enough statement to draw attention to the possessive adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a big accented TU. (Like you were about to shout it.)

> Estoy en TU país, por lo tanto hablaré Español.

Comment: Haha. I must really be over thinking things. It's really *that* simple, huh?

Comment: As a native speaker, I can tell it's just as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks so much. Feedback from a native speaker is extremely helpful.